# Red5 cannot resolve bean reference

Tags: java, spring, red5

I am working with Red5 0_9_1.

I have everything working fine on my local Windows dev. However, when I upload to the Linux server, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Launcher:/wieseservices_2"   
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error  
creating bean with name 'web.scope' defined in ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 
'web.handler' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested 
exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'web.handler' defined in ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]:
```

Here is the relevant section of red5-web.xml

```
<!--
Defines the web scopes
-->
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope"
     init-method="register">
    <property name="server" ref="red5.server" />
    <property name="parent" ref="global.scope" />
    <property name="context" ref="web.context" />
    <property name="handler" ref="web.handler" />
    <property name="contextPath" value="${webapp.contextPath}" />
    <property name="virtualHosts" value="${webapp.virtualHosts}" />
</bean>

<!--
Defines the web handler which acts as an applications endpoint
-->
<bean id="web.handler" 
    class="org.red5.core.Application" 
    singleton="true" />
```

Here are some things I've done/checked:
Both system are running 0.9.1
All folder and file names are correct

I'm at a complete loss here. As I said, it works just fine on my local Windows machine, but not with the Linux install.

Full stack trace:

```
    Exception in thread "Launcher:/wieseservices_2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'web.scope' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'web.handler' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'web.handler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:594)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'web.handler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2444)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2754)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2032)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: Okie, added. Thanks so much for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `ClassNotFoundException` which means the specified class is not available on your classpath. The class in question is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException
```

This class is part of JDK 7. You must be running your application with an older version of Java, ex JDK 6.

Comment: Thanks so much Sotirious for answering this. I hardly ever use Java, so even these otherwise simple issues can elude me.